# Occurrence vs Happening

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Please let me know if the word ["occurrence"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/occurrence)can be replaced with "happening" in the following example without any change in meaning?

If not, please let me know about the reason. Dictionary definitions do not seem to be quite to make any noticeable defference between these two words.

> - In late October 1929 the stock market crashed, wiping out 40 percent of the paper values of common stock. When the stock market crashed in 1929, it didn't happen on a single day. ... But over the weekend many investors lost faith in the stocks and decided to sell their shares. All those **[happenings](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/happening)** on the stock market could be interpreted in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Occurrence**" is used with a noun object (the thing or event that is occurring).
FOR EXAMPLE: Occurrence of theft, Occurrence of natural gas, Occurrence of death, etc.

While "**Happenings**" is a general word for anything that is happening.

As your sentence does not explicitly describes *what* is happening, occurrence wouldn't be used here.

Comment: I have added to my example. Please have a look on it again @Bella Swan. I guess "occurrence" does not work at all in this situation, while it has not happed all suddenly. Do you agree?

Comment: @A-friend Yes, Occurrence wouldn't be used here, but not because it has not happened suddenly, but because of the same reason I mentioned, i.e, a noun is not being mentioned here with the word.